# Javascript not working in TextWrangler

Tags: javascript, textwrangler

This is a color guessing game. However when I try to run it from TextWrangler nothing happens. But when I use a javascript editor online the game works perfectly. Is there something wrong with my code or is there a problem with TextWrangler???

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head> 
    <title>Guess the Color Assignment 2 Part 1</title>      
</head>     

<body onload=("do_game ()")>
<script type="javascript/text">
    var target_index;
    var guess_input_text= "none";
    var guess_input;
    var finished = false;
    var guess = 1;
    var colors=["blue","yellow","red","green","brown","black"];
    colors= colors.sort();      

    function do_game () {

        var random_number = (Math.random() * (colors.length-0)) + 0;
        var random_number_integer = Math.floor(random_number);
        target_index= random_number_integer;
        var target = String(colors[random_number_integer]);
        alert("" + target);     

        while (!finished) {
          guess_input_text = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors: \n\n" +
                                colors.join(",") + "\n\n What color am I thinking of?");

          guess_input = colors.indexOf(guess_input_text);
          guess += 1;
          finished = check_guess();
        }           
    }       


    function check_guess () {

        if(guess_input == -1) {
        alert("That is not is not option. Try again.  \n\n");
        return false;
        }

        if(guess_input > target_index) {
        alert("That color is alphabetically higher than the correct answer.");
        return false;
        }

        if(guess_input < target_index) {
        alert("That color is alphabetically lower than the correct answer.");
        return false;
        }

        if(guess_input == target_index) {
        alert("You are correct!!!!! You guessed the right color!" + "\n\n It took you " + guess + " tries to finish the game.");
        myBody=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        myBody.style.background= target;
        return true
        }
    }     
</script>
</body>
</html>
```